# Nesting AMPscript between ELSE and ENDIF in LookupOrderedRows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I'm using the LookupOrderedRows to populate an email with Apartment Suggestions.

Here's a simple version of the AMPscript:

```
   %%[
    var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i
    
    set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("SA_City__c") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
    set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("FLTR_Apartment_Salesforce",@numRowsToReturn,"Price__c asc, Number_of_bedrooms__c, Cover_picture__c, Code__c, Available_From__c, Street__c, Country_Code__c, Number_of_allowed_residents__c, Enabled_Booking_Modes__c","City__c", @lookupValue)
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
    
    if @rowCount > 0 then
    
      for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
    
        set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
        set @Price__c = field(@row,"Price__c")
        set @Number_of_bedrooms__c = field(@row,"Number_of_bedrooms__c")
        set @Cover_picture__c = field(@row,"Cover_picture__c")
        set @Code__c = field(@row,"Code__c")
    
        ]%%
    Row %%=v(@i)=%%<br>
    Code %%=v(@Code__c)=%%<br>
    Guests %%=v(@Number_of_allowed_residents__c)=%%<br>
    Cover Picture %%=v(@Cover_picture__c)=%%<br>
    Number of Bedrooms is %%=v(@Number_of_bedrooms__c)=%%<br>
    Price %%=v(@Price__c)=%%<br><br>
        %%[ 
      next @i ]%%
    
    %%[ else ]%%
    
    No rows found
    
    %%[ endif ]%%
```

What I want to do is basically replace the "No rows found" part with other AMPscript and HTML which will populate a "backup" apartment suggestion if the LookupOrderedRows function doesn't provide content.

I've tried this and the HTML loads, but the AMPscript doesn't. Example below:

```
...%%[next @i]%%%%[ELSE]%%
%%[
{{!-- apartment suggestion 1 --}}
SET @Cancellation_Flexibility__c_1 = AttributeValue("1_Cancellation_Flexibility__c")
SET @Cover_picture__c_1 = AttributeValue("1_Cover_picture__c")
SET @City__c_1 = AttributeValue("1_City__c")
SET @Enabled_Booking_Modes__c_1 = AttributeValue("1_Enabled_Booking_Modes__c")
]%%
    <div class="apartment"><table><tr><td style="width: 50%; height: 100%; padding-right: 3px;" class="responsive-td" valign="top"><img style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="%%=v(@view_apartment_suggestion_1)=%%" title="apartment_suggestion_1" alias="apartment_suggestion_1" conversion="true" data-linkto="other"><img data-assetid="109550" src="%%=v(@1_Cover_picture__c)=%%" style="display: block; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px; height: 200px; width: 270px;"></a></td>
        <td style="line-height:1.2;padding: 10px;"><b>%%=v(@1_Street__c)=%%, %%=v(@1_Postal_Code__c)=%%, %%=v(@1_City__c)=%%</b><br><br>%%=v(@1_Cancellation_Flexibility__c)=%%  %%=v(@1_Security_Deposit__c)=%%  %%=v(@1_Enabled_Booking_Modes__c)=%%<br><br><span style="font-size:13px">up to %%=v(@1_Number_of_allowed_residents__c)=%% persons<span style="padding: 2px;font-size:11px;color:#ffffff;"> • </span>%%=v(@1_Number_of_bedrooms__c)=%% bedrooms<span style="padding: 2px;font-size:11px;color:#ffffff;"> • </span>%%=v(@1_Number_of_bathrooms__c)=%% bathrooms</span><br><br><table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td align="left"><table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td class="innertd buttonblock" style=" border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #6699CC;" bgcolor="#6699CC"><a target="_blank" class="buttonstyles" style=" font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; background-color: #6699CC; border: 1px solid #6699CC; padding: 5px 40px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;" href="%%=v(@view_apartment_suggestion_1)=%%" title="View Apartment" alias="view_apartment_suggestion_1" conversion="false" data-linkto="other">View Apartment</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
        </td>
        </table></div><br>%%[ENDIF]%%
```

**How do I get the AMPscript to work in this case? Is there a function I should be using, such as Output()?**

Comment: Overall this looks ok given that you have mapped all DE columns correctly. You don’t need to use Output, you’re already using the `v` function which is better for your use case. Can you try removing that weird comment in curly brackets? Or replace the double curly brackets with the AMPscript comment tag `/* apartment suggestion */`

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing and removing the comments but this still didn't work, unfortunately. Any other suggestions on what I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I was able to resolve the issue, which was that AMPscript variables cannot start with an integer, such as @1_Name. I just needed to change the variable names and everything populated nicely.